# Delete from database with specific details in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to delete from database all row has a id include in some array or (key,value)

```
"recp" => "1, 2, 3 , 6, 7 , ........."
```

ID in `@recipient`

I try this:

```
 @v = NameOfDatabase.where.not(:id=> @recipient.split(',').map(&:to_i), :conditions => {:thread =>@dis_PI.m_id}).destroy_all
```

With specific condition i want to remove row with this condition and not include in `@recipient`

Error in this method :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x7f447f57b140>):
```

I try multiple code but not working, i put this question multiple time but also not work yet!

Comment: What is `NameOfDatabase`? An `ActiveRecord` model (inherited for `ApplicationRecord`)? Furthermore passing `:conditions` to `where` feels like you try to mix the very old and deprecated finder syntax with the up-to-date `where` method. What version of Rails do you use?

Comment: yes ActiveRecord , yes that it, what other metoh if my version is ruby 1.8.7

Comment: method***********

Comment: Ruby 1,8.7 reached its end of life 6 years ago. Why do you work with such an old version? Anyway: the finder methods are Rails methods, what version of Rails do you use?

Comment: project was made in old version :( i am obligated to work with this version....rake-0.8.7

Comment: We need to know the _Rails_ version to figure out what methods are available in your ancient version of _Rails_. Not Ruby, not Rake...

Comment: how i can find it?

Comment: When there is no `Gemfile` in your project (what I do not expect in such an old application then you should search for `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` in your `config/environment.rb`.

Comment: `#<Class:0x7f447f57b140>` looks very suspicious. Make sure that you call `where` on the right object. It should probably be `Recipient.where(...)`

Comment: @spickermann 1.3.2

Comment: @Stefan I do not benefit anything if my condition is where without of "not"

Comment: @tinoalberto re-read your error message again: it says ``undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x7f447f57b140>`` so the object you're calling `where` on doesn't know that method. That usually means that you are talking to the wrong object. You have to make sure that you send `where` to the correct object. Once that works, you can add more conditions, including `not`. But _first of all_ you have to get `where` working.

Comment: @Stefan same error undefined method `where'

Comment: There is no Rails 1.3.2 version. But given that your version of Rails is ancient anyway I tried to answer your question with a method that was available in other 1.x versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, I learned that you are running a very old version of Ruby on Rails – probably more than 10 years old. With Rails 3.0 the finder methods change completely and therefore all current documentation for Rails will not be helpful anymore. Especially the `where` method did not exist before Rails 3.0

In such an old version the following should work:

```
YourModel.destroy_all("id in (?)", @recipient.split(','))
```

Here you will find the docs of [older Rails versions](https://rubydocs.org/d/rails-1-2-6/).

The condition is basically just one SQL fragment. When you want to add more conditions then you need to write all conditions in one line like this:

```
YourModel.destroy_all(
  "id IN (?) AND thread = ?", @recipient.split(','), @dis_PI.m_id
)
```

Comment: I can use "id not in (?)"  ?? and if i want to add condition (:thread = @c) example how i can in this query?

Comment: In your question you wrote that you want to delete rows those `id` are in the `@recipient` list. If that is the case then you should use `id IN ...` and not `id not in ...` When you want to delete rows that are not in the list then, sure, feel free to use `id not in ...`.

Comment: TIL there was a time before `where` :-)

Comment: @spickerman can i use "@recip" in place of YourModel where "@recip = Recipient.find_all......." ?

Comment: Yes, prior to Rails 3.0 (in which Merb was merged into Rails) there was basically just the `find` method that took a number of options. Having `where` and all the other Relation methods since Rails 3.0 was a huge win...

Comment: @tinoalberto I do not understand that question about `@recip`. Since the original question was solved I suggest that you start a new question with more details and context.

Comment: @spickermann finally done!  i appreciate that bro, ruby i so beautiful but the old version almost ruined me